# How do i get a property JSON with Regular Expression in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, json, regex, string, object

**Hello Everyone!**

My main goal is to get a list of `object properties` of a `nested object`, using method `for loop` is too confusing for me, and it's very simple to use `Regex` by using the `JSON.stringify()` and `String.prototype.match()` methods.

**This is my JSON**

```
{
    "date": 153039023841,
    "name": "VEmpink",
    "item": {
        "brand": "Apple",
        "product": "iPhone SE 2016",
        "color": "Rose Gold"
    },
    "status": {
        "type": "process",
        "dateStatus": 153092315152
    },
    "dp": 0,
    "price": 700,
    "notes": null
}
```

**Expectation results**

```
[
    "date",
    "name",
    "item",
    "brand",
    "product",
    "color",
    "status",
    "type",
    "dateStatus",
    "dp",
    "price",
    "notes"
]
```

**My results** with pattern `/"(.*?)":/g`

```js
var myObj = {
    date: 153039023841,
    name: "VEmpink",
    item: {
        brand: "Apple",
        product: "iPhone SE 2016",
        color: "Rose Gold"
    },
    status: {
        type: "process",
        dateStatus: 153092315152
    },
    dp: 0,
    price: 700,
    notes: null
};

var getKeys = JSON.stringify(myObj).match(/"(.*?)":/g);
console.log(getKeys)
```

and also, I am a beginner in regex

Comment: So, who's "brad"?

Comment: do you only need the keys or the values too ? or both

Comment: only Object Keys

Comment: I got the expected output using your regex `/"(.*?)":/`

Comment: @xianshenglu in `.match()` method?

Comment: I don't see any way that your regexp can match `"Rose Gold"},` since the regexp requires `:` after the second `"`. That must be the output from a different attempt.

Comment: @Firmansyah yes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use recursion to iterate over the object and its nested objects and build a set of unique keys.

You should not parse JSON using a regular expression.

```js
const data = {
  "date": 153039023841,
  "name": "VEmpink",
  "item": {
    "brand": "Apple",
    "product": "iPhone SE 2016",
    "color": "Rose Gold"
  },
  "status": {
    "type": "process",
    "dateStatus": 153092315152
  },
  "dp": 0,
  "price": 700,
  "notes": null
};

const isObj = o => o?.constructor === Object;

const grabKeys = (obj, keys=new Set()) => {
  if (isObj(obj)) {
    for (let key in obj) {
      keys.add(key);
      grabKeys(obj[key], keys);
    }
  }
  return keys;
};

console.log([...grabKeys(data)]);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Comment: I am using `Regex` methods, because it's also useful for adding a new nested object in that object

Comment: @Firmansyah then that is a completely different question. You can still adapt, what you are saying, to this grabber function. Think of it as a "tree walking" function.

Answer (score 0):

I got expected result with pattern `/"(\w+)":/gi`

```js
var myObj = {
    date: 153039023841,
    name: "VEmpink",
    item: {
        brand: "Apple",
        product: "iPhone SE 2016",
        color: "Rose Gold"
    },
    status: {
        type: "process",
        dateStatus: 153092315152
    },
    dp: 0,
    price: 700,
    notes: null
};

var getKeys = JSON.stringify(myObj).match(/"(\w+)":/gi);
console.log(getKeys);
```

My problem with the pattern `/"(.*?)":/g` because `JSON.stringify()` begin `"` and it end `"`